# Out of memory error from Java stored procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, java

I have a Java stored procedure inside Oracle 11g database. The procedure uses lots of memory, so I'm setting the max memory size in same session:

```
create or replace function setMaxMemorySize(num number) return number
is language java name
'oracle.aurora.vm.OracleRuntime.setMaxMemorySize(long) returns long';
/

select setMaxMemorySize(4*1024*1024*1024) from dual;
```

I can confirm that max memory has been set:

```
create or replace function getMaxMemorySize return number
is language java name 'oracle.aurora.vm.OracleRuntime.getMaxMemorySize()
returns long';
/

select getMaxMemorySize() from dual;
4294967295
```

However, when I run my Java procedure, I get out of memory error from PostgreSQL JDBC driver that the program is using

```
Exception in thread "Root Thread" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
Ran out of memory retrieving query results.
...
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

But the same program (with same arguments) runs fine outside database by setting the memory limit as JVM argument.

Why is setMaxMemorySize not working? Is there some other parameter I need to set? Java Pool size is already set to 5 GB.

Comment: Just guessing, are you running 32bit or 64bit version of the database?

Comment: The database is 64 bit

Comment: Then I'm afraid it is best to contact Oracle support. Or try to use Oracle 12c, 11g still uses JVM 1.5.

Comment: What's the code in the procedure causing the out of memory error?